# Filtering a dask dataframe using a dictionary

Tags: python, filter, dask

I'm trying to filter a dask dataframe to only include certain time periods defined by a dictionary where the keys are ISO regions and the values are lists of timestamps.

This is a modified dictionary as an example.

```
iso_region_dict = {'MISO-E':[Timestamp('2016-05-17 22:15:00'),Timestamp('2016-10-21 13:45:00'),Timestamp('2016-12-26 02:45:00')], 'CAISO':[Timestamp('2016-08-24 10:15:00'),Timestamp('2016-07-03 14:30:00'),Timestamp('2016-04-22 12:45:00')]}
```

My dask dataframe looks like this (timeseries_ddf):

```
      building_id   time    electricity_cooling_kwh electricity_heating_kwh total_site_electricity_kwh  iso_zone
0   2   2016-01-01 00:15:00 0.0 0.0 4.082225    MISO-E
1   2   2016-05-17 22:15:00 0.0 0.0 5.627103    MISO-E
2   2   2016-10-21 13:45:00 0.0 0.0 21.547435   MISO-E
3   2   2016-12-26 02:45:00 0.0 0.0 4.082225    MISO-E
4   2   2016-10-21 14:00:00 0.0 0.0 21.547435   MISO-E
```

The full dataframe has thousands of building ids and the 'time' column is in datetime format ranging from 2016-1-1 to 2016-12-31 in 15-min intervals for each building_id.  I want to filter this dataframe to only include the timestamps in the time column that are defined in the iso_region_dict for each building_id.  This is a very large dataframe which is why I'm using dask.

Desired Output (timeseries_discharge_ddf):

```
building_id time    electricity_cooling_kwh electricity_heating_kwh total_site_electricity_kwh  iso_zone
    0   2   2016-05-17 22:15:00 0.0 0.0 5.627103    MISO-E
    1   2   2016-10-21 13:45:00 0.0 0.0 21.547435   MISO-E
    2   2   2016-12-26 02:45:00 0.0 0.0 4.082225    MISO-E
```

I have done something similar to this with a list of timestamps where I merely filter by:

```
timeseries_discharge_ddf = timeseries_ddf.map_partitions(lambda x: x[x.time.isin(discharge_timestamps)])
```

The added step that I am now trying to achieve is this filter but where the discharge_timestamps list changes depending on what the iso_zone is.

Comment: Hi kohare6, and welcome on SO. Please have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular you could explicitly define `iso_region_dict` and add the desired output.

Comment: @rpanai Thanks I updated it.  Is this format clearer?

Comment: It seems to me that it make more sense to have your `iso_region_dict` as dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that here it will be easier use merge or join.

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

diz_df = {'building_id': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'time': {0: '2016-01-01 00:15:00',
  1: '2016-05-17 22:15:00',
  2: '2016-10-21 13:45:00',
  3: '2016-12-26 02:45:00',
  4: '2016-10-21 14:00:00'},
 'electricity_cooling_kwh': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'electricity_heating_kwh': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'total_site_electricity_kwh': {0: 4.082225,
  1: 5.627103,
  2: 21.547435,
  3: 4.082225,
  4: 21.547435},
 'iso_zone': {0: 'MISO-E', 1: 'MISO-E', 2: 'MISO-E', 3: 'MISO-E', 4: 'MISO-E'}}

diz_filter = {'iso_zone': {0: 'MISO-E',
  1: 'MISO-E',
  2: 'MISO-E',
  3: 'CAISO',
  4: 'CAISO',
  5: 'CAISO'},
 'time': {0: '2016-05-17 22:15:00',
  1: '2016-10-21 13:45:00',
  2: '2016-12-26 02:45:00',
  3: '2016-08-24 10:15:00',
  4: '2016-07-03 14:30:00',
  5: '2016-04-22 12:45:00'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(diz_df)
df_filter = pd.DataFrame(diz_filter)
# converting to datetime
df["time"] = df["time"].astype("M8")
df_filter["time"] = df_filter["time"].astype("M8")
```

## Using `pandas`

```py
df_out = pd.merge(df, df_filter, on=["time", "iso_zone"])
```

## Using `dask`

```py
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
# It doesn't matter if the second dataframe is pandas or dask
# df_filter = dd.from_pandas(df_filter, npartitions=2)

df_out = dd.merge(df, df_filter, on=["time", "iso_zone"])
```

Comment: Really appreciate the response.  Exactly what I needed.